# mysql copy complete row data from one table to another with different fields

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-insert

I have a master table

```
id       Name       Value
2          A          4
4          A          5
6          B          8
8          C          9
```

and a history table which is the replica of master table but with a history_id

```
history_id   id       Name       Value
    1        2          A          4
    2        4          A          5
    3        6          B          8
    4        8          C          9
```

what I want to achieve is to copy the row of master table into `history_table` whenever change occurs in `master_table`

I am trying to do this way

```
INSERT INTO history_table
VALUES ('', SELECT * FROM master_table WHERE `id` = 8)
```

It is returning me error that the columns are not matching in both the tables. I hope I am trying it correctly if not then please suggest best approach for the task.

P.S: I do not want to mention the columns names and values static in the query as there are more than 50+ fields in table and any new change in the DB structure will fail the query in future.

Comment: Short answer is that you can't.  `history_id` is clearly a computed column *(probably AUTO_INCREMENT)* and to populate that table you're going to ***need*** to specify the columns you're inserting in to.  Even without such a column, you should ***still*** always specify the column names, as it is always possibly one table is defined as `a, b, c` and the other as `c, b, a`, in which case specifying names is the only way to put the data in the right place.  This is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and you should not even be trying to do this.

Comment: Is the column id in the master table AUTO_INCREMENT?

Comment: @forpas yes.. The id in master table and history_id in history table is AUTO_INCREMENT primary keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `INSERT ... SELECT` instead of `INSERT ... VALUES` and pass `NULL` for `history_id`:

```
INSERT INTO history_table
SELECT null, m.* 
FROM master_table m
WHERE m.id = 8;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c338b6ea00577dbe6a8f1c939a31938d).

Comment: Great.. That what I was looking for thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should list the columns being inserted and use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO history_table (id, name, value)
    SELECT id, name, value
    FROM master_table
    WHERE `id` = 8;
```

This assumes that `history_id` is set automatically (auto-incremented).

Your question refers to changes in values.  However, that has nothing to do with the error you have specified.  If you have a further question about detecting changes, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data, desired results, and explanation.

Comment: If I do it this way then my query will fail if the DB structure is changed in the future. Secondly If I follow this approach then every time I change the structure of DB I have to modify my query

Comment: I do not want to specify the column names and values in the query

Comment: @MuhammadAsifRaza . . .  Changing the structure of tables is a design flaw in your database.

Comment: @MuhammadAsifRaza - SQL is strongly typed; the number of columns, name of the columns, and their data-types, all matter.  If your schema is so volatile that you need code to be agnostic to the structure, something is very wrong.  At the ***VERY*** least, if the schema is volatile then that should be managed by some other software that has (or can read) meta-data describing the current structure.  That would then allow you to have code that writes the SQL *(so called "dynamic SQL")* to accomplish certain functionality.

Comment: @MuhammadAsifRaza Think this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp) will help out.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes you are right the DB stucture is volatile. as the requirement of the module I am working on are not well defined. Like I have to add few fields in the DB and then after month ago I have to add few more fields in the structure.  And I can do much about the requirement. Your solution works well when there are number of fields are same in both the tables. but every time histaroy table has 1 extra field as compared to master table i.e history_id which throws error of mismatching fields count in the query